# Change the size of label tag

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I made a dropdown menu using slide but I can't change the size of 'Categories' box even after using width in label tag

## html code

```
`<div class="nav-1">
  <label for="touch"><span>Categories</span></label>               
   <input type="checkbox" id="touch"> 
     <+ class="slide">
    <li><a>Lorem Ipsum</a></li>    
</div>`
```

I even used width in both label and input tag but couldn't change the size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the default `display` for the label is `inline`. That's why we cannot change the width, so we must change the `display` property.

You can use the following code:

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
}
```

The property `inline-block` will allow the label to have a width.

Here is some references:

- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) property,
- [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) property.